# WorkerService configure a RabbitMq with MassTransit

Tags: dependency-injection, rabbitmq, masstransit

in a WorkerService .Net I am trying to configure a MassTransit host with RabbitMq but I am getting this Error

> Reference to type 'IBusControl' claims it is defined in 'MassTransit', but it could not be found

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices((context,services) =>
{
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
    //MassTransit-RabbitMQ Configuration
    services.AddMassTransit(config => {
        config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) => {
            cfg.Host(context.Configuration.GetValue<string>("EventBusSettings:HostAddress"));
        });
    });
    services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
})
.Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are probably referencing an assembly that is not current. The latest version of MassTransit no longer requires the `AddMassTransitHostedService` configuration method. More details are available [in the documentation](https://masstransit.io/support/upgrade#addmasstransithostedservice-deprecated).